# list words of length 3 without duplication

Tags: shell, unix

how to list all word of length 3 without duplication ?

using `tr ' ' '\n' < cca1.txt | grep '^.\{3\}$'`

list all word of length 3

but when  add `sort -u` to be `tr ' ' '\n' < cca1.txt | grep '^.\{3\}$' |sort -u`

to list words of length 3 without duplication

it list part of words not whole words of length 3

any suggestion?

Comment: This seems perfectly ok and it works for me. Does the file `cca1.txt` contain any weird characters that could mess up the output? (Random guess -- Windows line breaks?)

Comment: it contains Arabic words "right to left language" only

Comment: maybe try to specify an arabic locale before running the command: LANG=ar_DZ  You should do that to get the correct sort order anyway.

Answer (score 1):

sort -u can be tricky.

simply use:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < cca1.txt | grep '^...$' | sort | uniq
```